# Java: Statistics for multiple CSV files

Tags: java, csv, statistics

I am working on a heuristic that I implemented in Java. The heuristic is tested on thousands of testing instances with different seeds. It generates a different folder for each seed and creates result files within these folders for every testing instance.

In order to analyse and compare these thousands of results I developed a little tool, that parses all result files and creates a result data sheet for every seed. The result sheet is a CSV-file that holds the name and result values for each instance in a separate line. A new CSV file is generated for every seed and placed in the appropriate seed-folder.

Now, I want a summary of all runs with different seeds. I have CSV file in mind that combines the results of all the runs. It should have new line for every instance and hold information calculated from the different results that are stored in the separate CSV files. It should have average-/min-/max-value of each instance's results.

Are there existing tools to do that? If not, are there special Java libraries that make the implementation easier?
At this point, I am unsure how to implement what I want because I have to compare thousands of different lines belonging to different CSV files and then combine these to a new CSV file.

Comment: Use a map from an instance name to an object of your design, which holds sum, min, max and count for an instance. Read all of your data sheets serially, get the instance name, retrieve the mapped object, apply each of the results to it (increment count, add to sum, update min and max). In the end, write the map to a csv.

Comment: Sounds appropriate for a custom solution of your own making. Your problem is very specific, thus is not likely to benefit from third party java libraries unless you're doing statistical analysis, in which case [look at this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/37480). In any case, the utility method [`Files.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) will surely come in handy for you.

Comment: @gknicker: So it would be easier and faster to use Files.readAllLines() rather than a Scanner that scans the file line by line?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying the individual CSV files were only one line each. If they are hundreds of lines long then you are better off with a Scanner, or even better a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Comment: No, the individual CSV files are also several thousands of lines long (close to 40000). So BufferedReader is the best way to go?